# Buy the server contents

Tags: 10.04

How i can buy the contents of the server of archive.ubuntu.com (for lucid lynx)? In my country i have ultra slow connection. It will take years for downloading all these gigabytes.

Because, canonical will stop supporting ubuntu 10.04, i want all the files now, before it's too late. i know that all files will be transfer to old.dir but i think some will be lost. And anyway i want the files.

My question is:
Can canonical provide (with payment) a disk with the contents of the server?

Cheers

Comment: Why not contact Canonical and ask?

Comment: Should we ask which country?

Answer (score 0):

***Random thought:***

*If **10.04.4 LTS** is no longer supported, then an install would not need (or have) any further updates.*

---

***Suggestion:***

Would it not be altogether better to try to arrange for *CD/DVD by Post* (from some helpful enthusiasts) for **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** server instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase complete repository dvd sets from various company's, usually 6-8 dvds or double that if both 32 & 64 bit

So just search the web till you find what you wish, obviously more recent Ubuntu releases would be more available. 
For example this shows up for 12.04 & seems ok, (16 dvd's) -

http://www.osdisc.com/cgi-bin/view.cgi/products/linux/ubuntu/ubuntu-1204-lts-software-repository-pc.html

An ex. of 10.04 would be here though  not sure how splitting 32 & 64 bit works out as .all.deb are 32 bit but still needed on 64 bit installs

32 bit - http://www.zyxware.com/shop/software/free-software/operating-systems/gnu-linux/ubuntu-10-04-i386-repository-8-dvd-pack

64 bit - http://www.zyxware.com/shop/software/free-software/operating-systems/gnu-linux/ubuntu-10-04-64bit-repository-8-dvd-pack

Comment: Thank you very much and the answer is answered more than i expected. Thank you. But is there a way that Canonical can provide these disks?

Comment: I guess they could but don't see why they would. (certainly not for free & there isn't much money/demand for these that hasn't been beyond what's supplied by the likes of what I posted above